# Построение диаграммы графа по координатам вершин в Excel

Tags: графы, excel

Необходимо построить в Excel диаграмму на основе координат 2-х групп вершин.
Вот как должен примерно выглядеть построенный график и соответствующие координаты вершин:
[image]

Проблема в том, что я не знаю, как указать координаты вершин для диапазонов данных. Сами координаты (на иллюстрации), например, такие:

```
X   Y
-----------
5   16
5   13
5   10
5   7,5
5   3,5
```

и

```
X   Y
-----------
12,5    15
12,5    8
```

Answer (score 1):

Задав координаты X наименованиями колонок и проставляя в качестве значений координаты Y соответсвующих векторов, что-то подобное соорудить получится. Конечно, не так красиво, как на скрине @srgg67, но Excel графики на такое просто не способны.

[image: Пример получаемого графика]

Answer (score 0):

Простым графиком такого не добиться. Совместить несколько?

[Неплохой ресурс по построению графиков](http://www.andypope.info/charts.htm)